# Lie derivatives for a differential forms-[derivation of Lee-smooth manifold]

Tags: lie-derivative

I have trouble of understanding Lee's textbook, Introduction to smooth manifold, about Lie derivatives for differential forms.

First let me state the content in textbook.

---

Let $A$ be a smooth contravariant $k$-tensor field on a smooth manifold $M$, and let $V, X_1, \dots, X_k$ be smooth vector fields on $M$. Then

$$\mathcal{L}_V(A(X_1, \dots, X_k)) = (\mathcal{L}_VA)(X_1, \dots, X_k) + \sum_{i=1}^kA(X_1, \dots, X_{i-1}, \mathcal{L}_VX_i, X_{i+1}, \dots, X_k).$$

Then what i want to prove is starting from this obtain

$$(\mathcal{L}_VA)(X_1, \dots, X_k) = V(A(X_1, \dots, X_k)) - \sum_{i=1}^kA(X_1, \dots, X_{i-1}, [V, X_i], X_{i+1}, \dots, X_k).$$

Textbook states it is nothing but application of

$\mathcal{L}_Vf = Vf$ for any smooth function $f$ on $M$  and $\mathcal{L}_VX = [V, X]$ for any vector field $X$ on $M$.

---

Now i got confusion, apparently, i can write

\begin{align}
(\mathcal{L}_VA)(X_1, \dots, X_k) &=  (\mathcal{L}_VA)(X_1, \dots, X_k) + \sum_{i=1}^kA(X_1, \dots, X_{i-1}, \mathcal{L}_VX_i, X_{i+1}, \dots, X_k) \\
& = V(A(X_1, \dots, X_k)) + \sum_{i=1}^kA(X_1, \dots, X_{i-1}, [V, X_i], X_{i+1}, \dots, X_k)
\end{align}
Here i have a trouble with the $+$ sign for the second term. The textbook and other references $i.e$, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Lie_derivative_of_tensor_fields)

How $-$ sign comes from?

I obtain the same formula from explicit computation from the Lie derivatives 
(via pullback, $\mathcal{L}_V w = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi_t^* w -w}{t}$) 
but i want to follow the textbook's approach.

Comment: The minus sign comes from moving the sum to the other side of the equation. Notice that in the desired result, the term with $(\mathcal{L}_VA)(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is on its own side of the equation.

Comment: @Nick, Oh i see, thanks for clarifying me.